# Comparing ranges of DATE fields to CURDATE() in MySQL without regard to year

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `closures` that consists of times when my client's business is closed:

```
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| id | start_date | end_date   | reason                        | yearly |
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2010-12-24 | 2011-01-08 | Holidays                      | 1      |
|  3 | 2011-01-03 | 2011-01-10 | testing purposes              | 1      |
|  5 | 2001-01-01 | 2001-01-10 | A non-yearly event            | 0      |
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
```

I have been trying to work out a query that checks if there are any rows in `closures` where CURDATE() lands within `start_date` and `end_date`. The crux is figuring out how to ignore the year if the row is marked `yearly` = '1'. Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT `id`,`reason`,`start_date`,`end_date`,`yearly` FROM `closures` 
WHERE ( CURDATE() BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date` ) /* full date with year is compared */
OR 
(
    `yearly` = '1' /* look for events marked yearly */
    AND
    (
        ( RIGHT( CURDATE() , 5 ) BETWEEN RIGHT( `start_date` , 5 ) AND RIGHT( `end_date` , 5 ) ) /* This WORKS for all date ranges marked yearly that do not go through new years */
        OR
        ( RIGHT( CURDATE() , 5 ) >= RIGHT( `start_date` , 5 ) AND RIGHT( `start_date` , 5 ) > RIGHT( `end_date` , 5 ) ) /* This DOES NOT catch date ranges that go through new years */
    )
)
```

Querying the table shown above, I get this:

```
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
| id | reason           | start_date | end_date   | yearly |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
|  3 | testing purposes | 2011-01-03 | 2011-01-10 | 1      |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

When I expect to get this:

```
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
| id | reason           | start_date | end_date   | yearly |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
|  1 | Holidays         | 2010-12-24 | 2011-01-08 | 1      |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
|  3 | testing purposes | 2011-01-03 | 2011-01-10 | 1      |
+----+------------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Am I on the right track? Is there a better/faster way of checking MM-DD of a DATE value than using RIGHT()?

Help me SO, I am not worthy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, i got it now!

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `closures` 
WHERE
    IF(`yearly` = '1',
        (
            IF(LEFT(`start_date`,4) < LEFT(`end_date`, 4),
                (
                    IF(RIGHT(CURDATE(), 4) > RIGHT(`end_date`, 4),
                        (CURDATE() BETWEEN CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 5), RIGHT(`start_date`, 5)) AND CONCAT((LEFT(CURDATE(), 4) + 1), RIGHT(`end_date`, 6))),
                        (CURDATE() BETWEEN CONCAT((LEFT(CURDATE(), 4) - 1), RIGHT(`start_date`, 6)) AND CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 5), RIGHT(`end_date`, 5)))
                    )
                ),
                (
                    CONCAT(LEFT(`start_date`, 5), RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5)) BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`
                )
            )
        ),
        (
            CURDATE() BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`
        )
    )
```

Comment: That does work except for when the closure starts at the end of december and goes to some date after january 1st. The concat will pick up the year from start date and the MM-DD from the CURDATE. So if the range of a closure was 2001-12-24 to 2002-01-10, if you ran the query today (2012-01-04), that last clause would compute to '2001-01-04' BETWEEN '2001-12-24' AND '2002-01-10', which would not work.

Comment: yeah, i saw that.. sorry. posted before i had tested. has no one else given you anything you can accept?

Comment: i tested this thoroughly. it also works correctly if the current date is '2011-12-29'. it only returns the first line in that case.

Comment: @DexterGordan remember to check out my revised answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM closures
WHERE (
CURDATE() BETWEEN
  IF(yearly=0,start_date,date_add(start_date, INTERVAL year(CURDATE())-year(start_date) YEAR))
AND
  IF(yearly=0,end_date,date_add(date_add(start_date, INTERVAL year(CURDATE())-year(start_date) YEAR), INTERVAL datediff(end_date, start_date) DAY))
) OR (
CURDATE() BETWEEN
  IF(yearly=0,start_date,date_add(date_add(end_date, INTERVAL year(CURDATE())-year(end_date) YEAR), INTERVAL -1*datediff(end_date, start_date) DAY))
AND
  IF(yearly=0,end_date,date_add(end_date, INTERVAL year(CURDATE())-year(end_date) YEAR))
)
```

should do the trick. The rocky edge is the year change, so I calculate the length in days of each closure and 1. add it from the corresponding start day of the current year and 2. subtract it from the corresponding end date of the current year.

Comment: Hmm... It seems to be catching the non-yearly events that, if marked yearly, would count. As I am not really familiar with the usage of IF in mysql queries, I'll have to look at this one for a while to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Could you provide an example? With yearly=0 this translates to SELECT * FROM closures WHERE (CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) OR (CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date), which I assume zo be correct

Comment: Here is the result when I run that query:
`+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| id | start_date | end_date   | reason                        | yearly |
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2010-12-24 | 2011-01-08 | Christmas and New Years break | 1      |
|  3 | 2011-01-03 | 2011-01-10 | testing purposes              | 1      |
|  5 | 2001-01-01 | 2001-01-10 | A non-yearly event            | 0      |
+----+------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+`
That last result is the issue

Comment: I just ran exactly the SQL from my answer against your data and it selected only the correct 2 rows - are you sure you don't have a copy/paste error?